# code to detect files in server and generate html file

Tags: php, html, video, auto-generate

Is there a way for some code to read all files in a directory on a server, and then make an html file for each of those files, changing only 1 element to the url of the file?

Basically:

> Code detects 100 videos on www.myserver.com/directorywithallvideos/
>
> Code creates 100 html files (1 per video)
>
> Code edits those html files  -> changes the source of the video
>   element to the detected video's url,   - maybe also change the title of
>   the html file to the video's name

**the generated html code is an html file used as a video page template that I made.**

the code should preferrably run on a cron job, like every 24 hours, so it can detect when new videos are uploaded, and do the same process on the newly uploaded videos.
Meaning that I want to do this in PHP, if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To build an array of files in the the Directory:

```
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files = scandir($dir);
```

To write the new files:

```
$file = $basepath . $filename;
$content =  file_get_contents($file);
// do whatever you want to the content
$newfile = $basepath . $newfilename;
file_put_contents($newfile, $content);
```

Obviously I would recommend adding some error handling etc to that.  Also make sure that the group \ user you're running your CLI on has write permission to the folder you're trying to write the files to.